# How to specify which rows should be kept by GROUP BY and which should be collapsed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

The application I am working on contains the part where users can create albums and upload images to it. The application creates several resizes of the image so that the large version is not served to the user. All the information about files is stored in the database in the following structure

1. Album table has an id and name
2. Photo table has a list of photos and each of them knows what album it belongs to
3. There also is a photo_versions. Each photo_versions stores the ID of an object from Photo table.

This logic is represented by the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE albums(`id` int, `name` varchar(255)); 
INSERT INTO albums (id, name) VALUES 
(1, "one"),
(2, "two"),
(3, "three");

CREATE TABLE photos(`id` int, `albums_id` int, `title` varchar(255));
INSERT INTO photos (id, albums_id, title) VALUES 
(1, 1, "a"),
(2, 1, "b"),
(3, 1, "c");

CREATE TABLE photos_versions(`id` int, `photos_id` int, `width` int, `height` int);
INSERT INTO photos_versions (photos_id, width, height) VALUES 
(1, 1000, 800),(1, 800, 600), (1, 600, 400),
(2, 1000, 800), (2, 800, 600), (2, 600, 400),
(3, 1000, 800), (3, 800, 600), (3, 600, 400);
```

User interface has the ability to request a specific height and the back end which I am working on should return the closest existing in database. I am working on request that should do it. It starts with joining all these tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN photos p ON p.albums_id = a.id
INNER JOIN photos_versions pv ON pv.photos_id = p.id;
```

That results in the following table:

```
+------+------+----+-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
| id   | name | id | albums_id | title | id   | photos_id | width | height |
+------+------+----+-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
|    1 | one  |  1 |         1 | a     | NULL |         1 |  1000 |    800 |
|    1 | one  |  1 |         1 | a     | NULL |         1 |   800 |    600 |
|    1 | one  |  1 |         1 | a     | NULL |         1 |   600 |    400 |
|    1 | one  |  2 |         1 | b     | NULL |         2 |  1000 |    800 |
|    1 | one  |  2 |         1 | b     | NULL |         2 |   800 |    600 |
|    1 | one  |  2 |         1 | b     | NULL |         2 |   600 |    400 |
|    1 | one  |  3 |         1 | c     | NULL |         3 |  1000 |    800 |
|    1 | one  |  3 |         1 | c     | NULL |         3 |   800 |    600 |
|    1 | one  |  3 |         1 | c     | NULL |         3 |   600 |    400 |
+------+------+----+-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, we need to group by photos_id (because we want to end up with the closest version of given photo). So, the request turns into that:

```
SELECT *
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN photos p ON p.albums_id = a.id
INNER JOIN photos_versions pv ON pv.photos_id = p.id
GROUP BY photos_id;
```

Which results in the following table:

```
+------+------+----+-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
| id   | name | id | albums_id | title | id   | photos_id | width | height |
+------+------+----+-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
|    1 | one  |  1 |         1 | a     | NULL |         1 |  1000 |    800 |
|    1 | one  |  2 |         1 | b     | NULL |         2 |  1000 |    800 |
|    1 | one  |  3 |         1 | c     | NULL |         3 |  1000 |    800 |
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, it does not necessarily keeps the row with the property (having the height closest to the one I specified). How do I GROUP BY the photos_id and choose the one with closest height?

P.S. SQL Fiddle is attached - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84f4f/1

Comment: What determines which row should be returned?  Where are you specifying the `height` in your query?

Comment: @sgeddes I do not, that is what my question is asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to add an additional join to your query which will restrict to photos having the closest height for each photo id group.

```
SELECT a.*, p.*, pv1.*
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN photos p
    ON p.albums_id = a.id
INNER JOIN photos_versions pv1
    ON pv1.photos_id = p.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT photos_id, MIN(ABS(height - SOME_HEIGHT)) AS diff
    FROM photos_versions
    GROUP BY photos_id
) pv2
    ON pv1.photos_id = pv2.photos_id AND
       MIN(ABS(pv1.height - SOME_HEIGHT)) = pv2.diff
```

You can replace `SOME_HEIGHT` with whatever value you obtain from the search by height.